# Xamarin.InAppBilling (2.2.0) Android BuyProduct() invoked but callbacks sometimes not invoked - How to diagnose/fix root cause?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services

The last couple of weeks we have been experiencing a number of failed In-App Purchase failures on Android (iOS has been fine).

We use the Xamarin.InAppBilling component (version 2.2.0) which has been absolutely fine for many months, but recently we can see that we are invoking line (A) but the usual IAP callbacks are not being invoked, which implies...

- Google doesn't receive the purchase request - we can rule this out, they are being charged.
- Google doesn't reply - Our most likely scenario
- A bug in the Xamarin.InAppBilling - unlikely since it has been working to date.
- We haven't registered a callback properly - unlikely because we have logging on the first line of each callback...

  ```
      _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.OnUserCanceled += BillingHandler_OnProductCanceled;
      _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.OnProductPurchased += BillingHandler_OnProductPurchased;
      _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.OnGetProductsError += BillingHandler_OnGetProductsError;
      _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.OnPurchaseConsumed += BillingHandler_OnPurchaseConsumed;
      _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.OnPurchaseConsumedError += BillingHandler_OnPurchaseConsumedError;
      _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.OnProductPurchasedError += BillingHandler_OnProductPurchasedError;
      _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.OnPurchaseFailedValidation += BillingHandler_OnPurchaseFailedValidation;
      _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.OnInvalidOwnedItemsBundleReturned += BillingHandler_OnInvalidOwnedItemsBundleReturned;
  ```

Here's an excerpt of the code that invokes the purchase...

```
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (async () => {

            var products = await _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.QueryInventoryAsync (new List<String> { consumableSku }, ItemType.Product);

            if (products != null && products.Count == 1) {

                var product = products [0];

                logger.Log ("FeatureService purchaseConsumableFromGooglePlay product:"+product.ToString()+ " payload:" + this.developerPayload);

                // (A)
                _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.BuyProduct (product, this.developerPayload);

            } else {
                this.iapConsumableEvent.Purchased = false;
                this.Publish<IapConsumableEvent> (this.iapConsumableEvent);
            }
        });

        logger.Log ("FeatureService purchaseConsumableFromGooglePlay completed");
```

Most of the time the BillingHandler callbacks are invoked, but when it doesn't work it seems that those callbacks are not invoked.

We have seen this on Android 7 and 8 (so it's an Android 8 issue).

We are not sure where to go from here, any suggestions on debugging this further is appreciated.

Comment: Attempting to tag @JamesMontemagno :-)

Comment: At this time, it's looking like Google Play aren't sending the usual intent through to my main activity (onActivityResult), therefore I don't call through to proxy it to my IAP handler.  I have noticed I also receive an update through a broadcast receiver (com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASES_UPDATED), so I've changed my code to listen for that, then iterate over the purchase instead.  If I find a consumable, I consume it and then resume as normal.  The problem is, sometimes we don't see that message either.  Circa 1 in 20 attempts might fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay,

As it turned out it was an issue at Google

> Thanks for your reply to Google Play Developer Support!
>
> Our team have recently made some changes that should fix this issue
>   (which is what you have confirmed).
>
> On the other hand, we do encourage developers to use our new Play
>   Billing library
>   (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html),
>   which gracefully handles most of use cases, and a good example of
>   integrating with it is our open-sourced sample:
>   https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive_v2
>   I appreciate your patience on this fix, I hope this helps! If you have
>   any further questions, please let me know. I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the Google's response (within your answer), Xamarin is using the "old" Google Play Billing Library, assuming `rev 5` if your Android SDK is up to date.

The newer library from Google has been finally released (`1.0`) that replaces the old methods and provides a new API. This new library (`.aar`-based) is available via maven and is not installed locally within Android SDK.

- `com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0`

Google Play Billing Library 1.0 released / 19 September 2017

- https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/09/google-play-billing-library-10-released.html

I been using it via a binding library and it is so much better to work with then the old one in terms of the API, server responses, and error handling  ;-)

Comment: Do you have c# sample? i try to convert this https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#pending

But 2 things i am stacked. Should you call BillingClient functions async on another thread and how to return values from listeners? java is easy but c# looks harder to implement.

Comment: i have just posted a question. if you can take a look please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58272917/how-to-implement-android-in-app-billingclient-in-xamarin-android-with-return-val